# Go: os.Stat ModTime shows incorrect value

Tags: linux, go

I am trying to get the file modification time consistently across operating systems.
I am creating a file, then using `info := os.Stat(file)` and then `info.ModTime()`.

On Windows, this looks as expected - file modification time equals now.
On Linux, it looks like the file was created in the past (12 seconds in the past to be exact).

I should mention my Linux is a virtual machine, using [this vagrant box](https://github.com/dcoxall/vagrant-golang).

The full script and its results are below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Started   :", time.Now())
    ioutil.WriteFile("somefile.txt", []byte("hello"), 0666)
    fi, _ := os.Stat("somefile.txt")
    fmt.Println("ModTime   :", fi.ModTime())
    fmt.Println("Now       :", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("Time Since:", time.Since(fi.ModTime()).Seconds())
}
```

**Windows Results (as expected)**

```
Started   : 2014-10-16 16:15:54.3861206 +0300 IDT
ModTime   : 2014-10-16 16:15:54.3880908 +0300 IDT
Now       : 2014-10-16 16:15:54.3880908 +0300 IDT
Time Since: 0
```

**Linux Results (12 seconds in the past)**

```
Started   : 2014-10-16 13:15:23.511700545 +0000 UTC
ModTime   : 2014-10-16 13:15:11.1473256 +0000 UTC
Now       : 2014-10-16 13:15:23.514631479 +0000 UTC
Time Since: 12.367389917
```

Any assistance as to what I am missing, would be great.

EDIT:
[Execution on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/DannyBen/travistest/builds/38173445) does NOT reproduce the error

Comment: Have you ruled out the system clock or filesystem? Does `touch somefile.txt && stat -c%y somefile.txt && date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S.%N %z"` match?

Comment: Try replacing the `touch` command with your go program, and see which times match; "ModTime", "Now", `stat`, or `date` (btw, I'm unable to repro on OSX or Linux).

Comment: Done. Replaced `touch` with `go run hello.go` - the result is as follows: `ModTime` by Go equals `stat somefile`, and `now` by Go equals `date`

Comment: hah, now I'm extra confused. Does it help to delete the old file before you test it? Can you try on another Linux system (distro and/or hardware)?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me here. Deleting the file does not change anything. The difference is consistent at ~12.3 seconds. I am currently using this vagrant box https://github.com/dcoxall/vagrant-golang - I may try a different box later (no hardware, but a different box maybe)

Comment: One more thing to try, does running `sync` (or `syscall.Sync()` in the go program) fix the file's mtime in stat?

Comment: Doesnt seem to. Added `syscall.Sync()` after the file write. Same.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machines are notorious for having their clocks get out of sync if you aren't running an NTP client to sync it.

If your working directory is local to your actual host machine and mounted by Vagrant through to the VM (which is typical when doing development), then the host file system will determine the modified time. If the VM and your host clocks have drifted apart enough, you will observe exactly this behavior.

Run `date` on both the host and VM systems at the exact same time to figure out how far apart the clocks are.